# jQuery IF statement for displaying/hiding a facebox

Tags: jquery, if-statement, facebox

Not sure I did this correctly, but here is my stab at JSfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/EQ4mA/2/

Let me preface this with admitting that I have little to no experience with jQuery (I am proficient with html/css), but my team has lost our development allotted hours, and I have been tasked with the following:

Create a 5 page flow
Create a facebox on page 3 of that flow
Style the facebox so that if a user is navigating FROM page 2 TO page 3, the facebox will display.
IF the user is navigating FROM page 4 TO page 3, the facebox must be hidden. That is to say, the user clicks the back button on page 4, the facebox should not appear on page 3.

The good news: I have created a (functioning, yay!) facebox on page 3, however, I am at a loss where to go next. My flow works and functions great, but I have no clue how to have the facebox only display from page 2 to 3, and not from 4 to 3.

I have:

```
jQuery(document).ready(
function() {
if("${user.last_mbox_before_choice_page}" != 'Act 3 Sidebar Profile') {
jQuery('#premier_interstitial_main').hide();
jQuery('.pagebody_div').show();
}
```

I'm guessing I'm missing a var = statement, but I'm not sure how those work. Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Just at a quick glance your conditional operator should be !==. Fix that, try it and let me know. Then we can look further into it. Also, if you are familiar with JSfiddle.net you can use that to provide a smaller scale example of what you are doing, which is extremely helpful when trying to troubleshoot these kinds of issues.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @wrxsti! Unfortunately that didn't do it :(. Thank you for the JSfiddle tip, I'm going to take a look at that now too!

Comment: Yeh man! Put up a small example and edit your question with the JSfiddle link, and I will gladly look it over with you!

Comment: thanks! I'm not entirely sure I did that correctly, but I've included the link above. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
if("${user.last_mbox_before_choice_page}" != 'Act 3 Sidebar Profile') {
jQuery('#premier_interstitial_main').hide();
jQuery('.pagebody_div').show();
}
```

to:

```
if(${user.last_mbox_before_choice_page} !== "Act 3 Sidebar Profile") {
jQuery('#premier_interstitial_main').hide();
jQuery('.pagebody_div').show();
}
```

You shouldn't put quotes around variables, because then it will treat them as a string, and obviously, the two strings don't match :)
Also, the operator ("!=") was not correct. You want to use "!==", which means different type or different value. You can read more about operators here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @DarthCaniac! Unfortunately removing the quotations hides the Facebox altogether. Adding them back in has the facebox show again. Your comparisons link is very helpful!